# Transaction priority?

Tags: php, mysql

I have crons what run script each 3 minutes, script contains function what:

```
try
   begin transaction
   loop
     //parse large xml data
     //send data to database
   endloop
   commit
endtry
catch
   rollback
endcatch
```

Now, data insertion is long process what takes about 3-6 minutes, and cron is each 3 minutes, so there is sometimes process conflict. 
I see when i add commit inside loop that priority has new process, **can i somehow say hey new transaction wait until before transaction commit?**

Comment: if you can't get a lock on a trivial/dedicated sentinel table, call it MyISAM, or a ROW (INNODB), then bail out. But **fear not**, you can try again in 3 minutes :>

Comment: Yes, flag that a cron is running in some way, then each time it starts it checks to see if it should run or just exit. You could simply create a file on disk, or set a column on a database table etc etc, there are many things you could do to achieve this. You could even use a [MUTEX](http://php.net/manual/en/mutex.lock.php)

Comment: smart idea @RiggsFolly , is there way to check is some transaction active?

Comment: What OS are you using

Comment: It is web linux server

Comment: Maybe better question is how to check is transaction active using php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try and Keep It Simple S....., and use a simple file locking process like this at the top of your existing cron script.

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/my_cron_lock.txt", "r+");

if ( ! flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    // other cron is overrunning so
    // I'll get restarted in 3 mins 
    // so I will let other job finish

    fclose($fp);

    exit;
}

// existing script



// free the lock, 
// although this will happen automatically when script terminates

    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: You think that i write in cron_lock state of transaction, if is finished than start new?

Comment: The file does not need to contain anything, all we are doing is using its existance and the ability to allocate it exclusively as the method of deciding another of these cron jobs is running.

Comment: If you only have to wait a max of 3 mins its probably not necessary to start the next one from here.

Answer (score 1):

You can store some lock somewhere persistent, typically that is done in some lock file in a file system:

The process first checks if a file already exists. If so, it exits right away. 
If no lock file exists it creates the lock file itself and writes its own process id into it. When terminating, it again checks if that is still its own lock file (by the process id) and removes it if all is fine.

That way you can fire your trigger script (cron job) every minute without any risk.

The same can be done on database or even table level. However that can be less robust depending on the situation, since it obviously fails if there is an issue with the database connection. The less layers are involved, the more robust. And as always: you have to decide yourself what approach is the best. But in general: locking is the answer.